# How do I get a better understanding on how to read Flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-test

The thing is I get confused on the work flow of the program and then pages we navigate to and widgets we import from different files we create. How do I get a better grip on understanding all that along with the concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can do to help you is sharing my path, so that you can start somewhere. Warning: opinions ahead, not actual data or best-practices are involved (I'm not like an expert here).

First thing to do if you want to learn Flutter: go on platforms like Udemy, spend like $10 and receive a full well-made course. I did my first steps with [this course](https://www.udemy.com/share/1013o42@FG5gVGJbTlYMekNBAXpNfj5tY1dL/), which to be honest is the best one for starters and beginners.

1. DO organize your App into small and smaller widgets, so that you actually follow some sort of logic. Disregard building with functions returning Widgets (it's also a matter of efficiency!);
2. DO separate UI building from business logic and/or service requests (e.g. http), i.e. distinguish between models, state, ui and logic.

Here's an **example** (i.e. this is not a rule of thumb, and instead it's just something that works for me) on a recent project I've been working on:

### 1. Project Organization

```
+/lib  [the whole project]
|
+--/models
|  |
|  +[heres a bunch of .dart files, each representing a data model, i.e. classes]
|
+--/providers
|  |
|  + [State management. I choose Riverpod, so I use providers.]
|  + [Therefore, here you find logic and state management .dart files]
|
+--/widgets
|  |
|  + [Widgets that are REUSED across the WHOLE APPLICATION]
|  + [It doesnt happen very often, so there arent many .dart files here]
|  + [Note. It is not WIDGET<=>NEW FILE. It is: ""big"" widget <=> NEW FILE]
|  + [Note 2. I rather create private widgets within the same file to keep things organized]
|
+--/screens
|  |
|  + [In here, there are as much subfolders as screens to be rendered]
|  + [In my mind, a screen not necessarly translates in a Scaffold]
|  |
|  +--/screen1/... [list of .dart files - widgets for this screen]
|  +--/screen2/...
|  +--/screen_with_multiple_tabs_and_bottom_bar/
|     |
|     +mainScaffold.dart
|     +/tab1/... [list of .dart files - widget for this tab]
|     +/tab2/...
```

Again, this is just a random example. I like to "organize" my projects in some way that I can easily track routing, while separating widgets, logic, models and utils. I believe the above schema is self-explaining. If not, let me know.

### 2. State management

I've had a lot of confusion in this framework when it comes to state management. At the moment Google is well-prone to listen to the community to bring the best state management solution to the public: at the moment there is no clear "winner" between the solutions on the market.

If you feel "confused" on choosing a state management package, I'd strongly recommend the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package, to begin with, which was made with a strong effort by a committed person in the Flutter community. This package is a wrapper around the so-called `InheritedWidget`, so it's *very* Flutterish, I totally recommend to check it out. [Even Google dropped their own state management solution and adopted this one (2019)](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I), even if they're still looking for improvements.

No one will hate on you if you use other non-flutterish solutions such as [injection](https://github.com/GIfatahTH/states_rebuilder), or [hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks), or [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) (or others...) but I (personally!) think that a Framework is working for you, and not viceversa, so why swim against the current :)

I personally use [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/), which is a `Provider` improvement, made by the same person. But if you're new to Flutter, just learn `Provider` first.

I've been hearing that a strong and production-ready solution is [BLOC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). But it's hard stuff. It's easy to get overwhelmed, just start with the basics (Provider), then learn some more and choose.

I hope this answered a little.

Comment: Thank you so much, also I'm already enrolled in this course!! And I'm finding a bit overwhelming when I try to read the code. I again start watching the course videos to understand what I did in the 1st place there.